# How to check which framework used DefaultMallocZone in VMMap

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, vmmap

I have a memgraph file for my project which is exported from Xcode. Trying to analyze which framework using more memory. I was able to see which framework using __DATA.But unable to check which framework allocated the following memory

```
                 VIRTUAL RESIDENT    DIRTY
```

MALLOC_SMALL         64.0M    1280K    1264K

MALLOC_TINY.         13.0M    3264K    3264K

DefaultMallocZone_0x104858000    55.8M      4768K      4752K

Appreciate your help in advance